# draw-function with fold and add-line?

Tags: recursion, scheme, draw, fold

I have a question about a recursive function to draw an image

Yes, it's a homework, but I don't know how to draw that image. What I have so far is:

- A function that gives me a list of points(x/y) from a curve(`(list (x1/y2) (x2/y2)...(xn/yn)`)
- To get a x-coordinate for example I have to write `point-x (first lis)`
- A function I called `(zipWith f xs ys)`that takes two lists(`xs ys)` apply the function `f` and makes a list (for example `(zipWith + (list 1 2 3) (list 10 20 30)) -> (list 11 22 33)`)
- A function `make-tuple` that takes two lists and makes them a tuple (for example:
  `(make-tuple (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6)) -> (tuple (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6))`
  To get the first tuple I have to write `(xs1 (tuple (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6)) -> (list 1 2 3)`

Now to the actual function:

We have to use the function `add-line` which draws a line from one point to another.
The parameters are `image number number number number string`
In other words: `empty-image x1 y1 x2 y2 "black"`
So it starts with an `empty-image` and draws a line from `(x1/y1)` to `(x2/y2)` with the color `"black"`

And we have to use `fold` to write the function. So my attempt on this:

```
;Signature
(: render ((list-of point) -> image))

(define render
  (lambda (xs)
    (let((tuple-list (zipWith make-tuple xs (rest xs))))
      (fold empty-image
            add-line
            tuple-list))))
```

What I tried to do was take the list of points and make a list with tuple of points
 `(list (tuple (x1/y1) (x2/y2)) (tuple (x2/y2) (x3/y3))...(tuple (xn/yn) (xn/yn)))`
Now I want to apply `add-line` with `fold` to the list of tuples. So that I say, lets take the first tuple (my two points) and apply them to the function `add-line`. Then take the next tuple and also apply these points to the `add-line` function (and so on) until my list is empty.

The problem now is, Scheme says *`add-line` expects 6 parameters but found only 2*. I know my problem, because `add-line` don't know where to get the other parameters. So I tried:

```
(define render
  (lambda (xs)
    (let((tuple-list (zipWith make-tuple xs (rest xs))))
      (fold empty-image (add-line 
                         empty-image
                         (point-x (xs1 (first tuple-list)))
                         (point-y (xs1 (first tuple-list)))
                         (point-x (xs2 (first tuple-list)))
                         (point-y (xs2 (first tuple-list)))
                         "black")
            tuple-list))))
```

and know it says *"function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but received an image"*

And again I know my mistake, `add-line` draws one line, and fold tries to apply that image to the list, but need a function not an image. So my question:

How can I write a recursive function `render` with `add-line` and `fold`, that draws the first line, then get the next points and draws the next line combined with the first one?
(like a recursive `add-line` function, that calls itself again after drawing a line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say specifically which language you are using,
but this looks suspicious:

```
 (fold empty-image (add-line ...))
```

In Racket the way to use `fold` is:

```
 (foldl f base l)
```

Here `f` is a function. In your code you have `empty-image`.

You need to define define a function say `f`, that use a tuple to add a line onto the "current" image:

```
 ; f : tuple image -> image
 (define (f t img)
     (add-line img
               (point-x (xs1 t))
               (point-y (xs1 t))
               (point-x (xs2 t))
               (point-y (xs2 t))
               "black"))
```

and then

```
(foldl f empty-image tuple-list)
```

You might need to tweak a thing or two to get it to work.